# Fullpage Live Video Stream on Mobile

Tags: ios, html, video, mobile, live-streaming

I am building a mobile web app that will integrate with a live video stream. The streaming stuff is all handled by a third party so I don't need to worry about that aspect.

What I get from the third party is an iFrame/video element to drop onto the page. I am curious if there is a way to have this video play in the background while the user can interact with a UI over top.

I am aware of the limitations involving mobile browsers and `autoplay`, so I know that at the very least the user will need to initiate an action. I am just worried that the native video player will pop up and the UI will be hidden beneath it.

So my primary question would be is this even possible?

Answer (score -1):

A little google search would have given you an answer

http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I've seen that already and it just sets the video to a static BG image on mobile, so it isn't what I was looking for. A little read through of the article you just posted would have given you the answer.